# How to convert path into json in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm getting values in the below format

```
/a/b/c/d="value1"
/a/b/e/f="value2"
```

I want these values in the below format.

```
{
    "a": {
        "b": {
            {
                "c": {
                    "d": "value1"
                }
            },
            {
                "e" {
                    "f": "value2"
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

}

Are there any built-in functions in python that can do this job as I could `a["b"]["c"]["d"]` kind of structure is not possible in the python dictionary?

Comment: A simple approach would be to consider this as a recursion problem for the paths then write it to a dictionary

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested in above msgs, I created a recursive function which split path["a/b/c"] and it's value["value1"] and create an output_dict will store all the values in json/dict format.

```
resources={"/a/b/c/d":"value1","/a/b/e/f":"value2"}
output_dict = {}

def create_nested_dict(path, value, output_dict):
    """Create a nested dictionary from the given path and value."""
    keys = path.split("/")
    if len(keys) == 1:
        output_dict[keys[0]] = value
    else:
        key = keys[0]
        if key not in output_dict:
            output_dict[key] = {}
        create_nested_dict("/".join(keys[1:]), value, output_dict[key])



for resource in resources:
    for path,value in resource.items():
        create_nested_dict(path[1:], value, output_dict)
```

Answer (score 1):

Feels a bit hacky, but if you want to go with the `a["b"]["c"]["d"]` route, you could use [`collections.defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) to do it.

```
from collections import defaultdict

def defaultdict_factory():
    return defaultdict(defaultdict)

a = defaultdict(defaultdict_factory)

a["b"]["c"]["d"] = "value1"
```

Answer (score 1):

Built-in no, but you can `reduce` each of these expressions to a dictionary and then get their union.

```
from functools import reduce

data = """
/a/b/c/d="value1"
/a/b/e/f="value2"
"""

exp = dict()
for pathexp in data.strip().splitlines():
    # skip past first "/" to avoid getting an empty element
    path, value = pathexp.lstrip("/").rsplit("=", 1)
    exp.update(
        reduce(lambda x, y: {y: x}, reversed(path.split("/")),
               value.strip('"')))

print(exp)
```

If you *really* wanted to, you could fold this into a one-liner with another `reduce` instead of the loop; but unless you are really into functional programming, this is already rather dense.